# Zuul seems to rewrite routes after REST call

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have encountered a strange behaviour with our Zuul-Proxy in our Microservice-Project. My Setup consists of a Discovery-Service (Eureka), an API-Gateway (Zuul) and two Microservices "A" & "B".
After starting the setup, the following routes are shown via "localhost:10000/routes":

```
{
  "/api-gateway/**": "api-gateway",
  "/a-service/**": "a-service",
  "/b-service/**": "b-service"
}
```

My Zuul Config looks like this:

```
zuul:
  ignored-services: ''
  add-proxy-headers: true
  sensitiveHeaders: 'Cookie,Set-Cookie'
```

Now I access the services via the gateway and make some REST calls:

http://localhost:10000/a-service/sayHello --> OK

http://localhost:10000/b-service/sayBye --> OK

http://localhost:10000/a-service/sayHello --> ERROR 404

I can see that the last request is mistakenly routed to Service B, even though I am using the "/a-service/**" route. How can this happen? Did the second REST call to service B somehow rewrite the routing?

However "localhost:10000/routes" is still returning the same as above. This also works with calling the services in opposite order B-A-B -> 404 and mistakenly routed to service A.

You can download a minimal project with the 4 components, which should let you easily replicate this behaviour here:
https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/files/827817/MinimalZuulRouteBugProject.zip

Thank you, for any insights regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from spencergibb @github:

This is a documented issue here http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR5/#_customizing_the_ribbon_client

> The FooConfiguration has to be @Configuration but take care that it
>   is not in a @ComponentScan for the main application context, otherwise
>   it will be shared by all the @RibbonClients. If you use @ComponentScan
>   (or @SpringBootApplication) you need to take steps to avoid it being
>   included (for instance put it in a separate, non-overlapping package,
>   or specify the packages to scan explicitly in the @ComponentScan).

In your case RibbonConfigAvailability is picked up by the component scan and shared between all ribbon clients (which is bad). Either remove the @Configuration (it doesn't have to be annotated as such, this is how I tested) or exclude it from component scanning.

The wrong Code:

```
@Configuration //THIS ANNOTATION IS THE ERROR    
public class RibbonConfigAvailability {

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule() {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }

}
```